# Mysql trigger SELECT INTO X

Tags: mysql, triggers, count

Hi i have a table as here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5be76/4 the table holds a list of removals and there drivers. Each removal can have multiple drivers but must have at least one.
I'm trying to identify when there are < 1 driver per removal job. I will use this information in a trigger to stop the deletion of the driver from the driver table if he is the only one on a job.

Have this so far but I seems to count all drivers on all jobs that don't include the deleted driver.

```
DECLARE x INT;
SELECT COUNT(a.driver_name)
INTO x
FROM drives a
WHERE a.start_time =
        (SELECT b.start_time 
            FROM drives b
            WHERE a.date = b.date
            AND a.driver_name != OLD.driver_name
            );
```

Comment: There is no "list of removals" in your table nor is one referenced by your table. If there was then it'd be trivial to add a trigger - but how do you propose forcing the operation to fail?

Comment: with a call to a non-existence procedure. The drives table holds the removals. With each having a date,start time and driver.

Comment: @Ian - is it <1 or >1. i think correct one is >1